# ssh and being prompted for a passphrase when none exists

Tags: ssh

I created keys without a passphase on server A

I place the keys on server B:
    git_id_rsa
    git_id_rsa.pub

I ran:
     cat ~/.ssh/git_id_rsa.pub > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys

created a ssh config:

```
Host *github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git_id_rsa.pub
```

I try and do a git clone via ssh.  I am promoted for a passphase

```
git clone git@github.com:test/test-chef.git
Cloning into 'test-chef'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/git_id_rsa.pub':
```

So...how do I deal wit ha passphrase where there should be none?

Comment: Can you give the exact command and output you had when you generated the key pair?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/587739/how-do-deal-with-ssh-config-and-and-passphrase/587741#587741

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the public key instead of the private key as SSH key.

[how do deal with ssh config, and and passphrase](https://serverfault.com/questions/587739/how-do-deal-with-ssh-config-and-and-passphrase/587741#587741)