# how do deal with ssh config, and and passphrase

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Why oh why am I being asked for a passphase when cloning from github??

```
git clone git@github.com:test/testchef.git
Cloning into 'chef'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/git_id_rsa.pub':
```

here is my ssh config file:

```
Host *github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git_id_rsa.pub
```

if I run from fabric..I get no error but I get prompted for the passphase if I try and clone
    def bootstrap():
       put('ssh_config','/root/.ssh/config')
       put('git_id_rsa.pub','/root/.ssh/git_id_rsa.pub')
       put('git_id_rsa','/root/.ssh/git_id_rsa')
       run("""chmod 600 /root/.ssh/git_id_rsa*""")
       run("""eval `ssh-agent -s`;ssh-add /root/.ssh/git_id_rsa""")

relevant output from fabric:

```
[107.170.196.221] out: Agent pid 2285
[107.170.196.221] out: Identity added: /root/.ssh/git_id_rsa (/root/.ssh/git_id_rsa)
[107.170.196.221] out:
```

I log into the server and run the below from the command line
    eval `ssh-agent -s`;ssh-add /root/.ssh/git_id_rsa
    git clone git@github.com:test/testchef.git

..great..I can clone without asking for a passphase.  Why did not it work from fabric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the identity file is the private key, not the public key:

```
Host *github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git_id_rsa # Without the .pub
```